# Finding out that a git repository has changed

Tags: git

I'm looking for a pragmatic way of finding out if a git repository has changed in any way (new commits, new branch, etc.). The purpose of finding an answer to this question is to create a simple caching system in web repository viewer, with proper invalidation.

See: https://github.com/klaussilveira/gitlist/issues/260 for more info. Thanks in advance, guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My naive approach would be to store and compare the output of `git show-ref`. If a branch is updated, then the corresponding head will be at different SHA at next `show-ref`, and if a branch is added it will appear as a new entry. Idem for tags.

It's a cheap command so it should scale OK on your 20k repos.

Comment: Works like a charm, specially with the pattern matching and the --heads and --tags options. :)

Answer (score 1):

What about `git remote show <remote-name>`?  You get output for each branch like this:

```
  Remote branch:
  master tracked
   Local branch configured for 'git pull':
   master merges with remote master
   Local ref configured for 'git push':
   master pushes to master (local out of date)
```

Comment: This wouldn't work with bare repos. I'm not looking to track remote changes, but any change at all in the repo (be it bare or not).